# Communicate Spring Security login status to angularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-social

I have an application that uses Spring Security, Spring Social, and AngularJS.

We are still using JSP views, but everything on the front end is controlled by angular.

I want to be able to communicate to the front-end that a login (preferably just if a social login) has just occurred. I don't know the proper way to do this.

Should I put a parameter in the query string, or set a cookie, or what? I want to preform AJAX calls and pop up a modal based on the result of those calls, but I only want to preform the call if a login has just occurred (they were redirected to the page as a result of a successful login).

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you consider a websocket?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with websockets. Is that something I should look into?